# Динамический SELECT без обновления страницы

Tags: php, ajax

Как правильно сделать, чтобы при выборе из `SELECT` без обновления страницы появлялся второй `SELECT` и показывал некоторую информацию из базы данных.

Первый `SELECT` включает в себя имена пользователей из базы. Выбрав имя, второй должен отображать (`OPTION`) магазины, присущие для выбранного пользователя.

Вроде все сделал, но при выборе из первого `SELECT`, показывается второй и происходит обновление страницы.

```
<?php
session_start ();
ini_set('error_reporting', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$response = array();
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';
$con = new DB_CONNECT();
$con->connect();
 if (isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['balans_medaxil'], $_POST['balans_mexaric'], $_POST['info'], $_POST['melumat'])) {
    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $info = $_POST['info'];
    $melumat = $_POST['melumat'];
    $balans_medaxil = $_POST['balans_medaxil'];
    $balans_mexaric = $_POST['balans_mexaric'];
    $data = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $date = new DateTime($data);
    $data=$date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn, "SELECT * FROM kassa WHERE id > 0") or die(mysqli_error($con->myconn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn,"DELETE FROM `kassa_print` WHERE `id` >0"); 
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn,"INSERT IGNORE INTO `kassa_list` (`uid`,`user_name`, `balans_medaxil`, `balans_mexaric`, `data`, `info`, `melumat`) VALUES ('".$row['uid']."','".$user_name."', '".$balans_medaxil."', '".$balans_mexaric."', '".$data."', '".$info."', '".$melumat."')");
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn,"INSERT IGNORE INTO `kassa_print` (`id`,`uid`,`user_name`, `balans_medaxil`, `balans_mexaric`, `data`, `info`, `melumat`) VALUES ('1','".$row['uid']."','".$user_name."', '".$balans_medaxil."', '".$balans_mexaric."', '".$data."', '".$info."', '".$melumat."')");
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn,"UPDATE `kassa` SET user_name='".$user_name."',balans_medaxil = balans_medaxil+'".$balans_medaxil."',balans_mexaric = balans_mexaric+'".$balans_mexaric."',info='".$info."',melumat='".$melumat."' WHERE user_name='".$user_name."'");  
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn,"UPDATE `kassa` SET user_name='".$user_name."',balans_borc = balans_borc-'".$balans_medaxil."',info='".$info."',melumat='".$melumat."' WHERE user_name='".$user_name."'");  

    
}
if (isset($_POST['user_name'], $_POST['balans_medaxil'], $_POST['balans_mexaric'], $_POST['info'], $_POST['melumat'])) {header('Location: https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); exit;}

}
?>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<style>
table {
    background-color: #eee;/* Цвет фона блока */
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
th {
  padding-left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;  
  background: black; /* Цвет фона блока */
  color: #FFFAFA; /* Цвет текста */
  text-align: center;
}
td {
  color: black; /* Цвет текста */
  padding-left: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #E6DFC3;

}
table#t01 tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background-color: #F6F6F6;
}
table#t01 th {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
fieldset {
  display: block;
  background: #EEEEEE; /* Цвет фона блока */
    color: #FFFAFA; /* Цвет текста */
     height: 40px;
}
hr {
    background: #008577; /* Цвет фона блока */
    color: #FFFAFA; /* Цвет текста */
     height: 1px;
     display: block;
   }
   
#close-CSS {
    display: inline-block;
    background: url( '/img/list.png' ) no-repeat /*-40px left*/;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    background-size: 45px 45px;
}
input[type="submit"] {
        border: 0;
        background: url( '/img/new_icons_add.png' ) no-repeat /*-40px left*/;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        line-height:3000;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-size: 50px 50px;
}
input[type="button"] {
        border: 0;
        background: url( '/img/new_icons_refresh.png' ) no-repeat /*-40px left*/;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        line-height:3000;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-size: 50px 50px;
}
input[type="button1"] {
        border: 0;
        background: url( '/img/anbar.png' ) no-repeat /*-40px left*/;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        line-height:3000;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-size: 50px 50px;
}
input[type="button2"] {
        border: 0;
        background: url( '/img/list.png' ) no-repeat /*-40px left*/;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        line-height:3000;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-size: 50px 50px;
}
input[type="image"] {
        border: 0;
        background: url( '/img/kassa_p_buy.png' ) no-repeat /*-40px left*/;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        line-height:3000;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-size: 50px 50px;
    }
    input[type="image1"] {
        border: 0;
        background: url( '/img/kassa_p_sell.png' ) no-repeat /*-40px left*/;
        text-indent: -9999em;
        line-height:3000;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-size: 50px 50px;
    }
input[type=text]:focus {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
input[type=number]:focus {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
input[type=datetime-local]:focus {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 13%;
  background-color: lightblue; /* Цвет фона блока */
  color: black; /* Цвет текста */

}
input[type="datetime-local"] {
  position: absolute;
  left: 450px;
  top: 3px;
  z-index: +1;
  width: 13%;
  border: 0px solid #555;
  background: #008577; /* Цвет фона блока */
  color: black; /* Цвет текста */
    }
textarea:focus {
  background-color: lightblue; /* Цвет фона блока */
  color: 0D212F; /* Цвет текста */
}
select {
    position: absolute;
  left: 420px;
  top: 12px;
  z-index: +1;
  width: 13%;
  border: 0px solid #555;
  background: #008577; /* Цвет фона блока */
  color: white; /* Цвет текста */
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  
   }
  .car {
    position: absolute;
  left: 620px;
  top: 12px;
  z-index: +1;
  width: 13%;
  border: 0px solid #555;
  background: #008577; /* Цвет фона блока */
  color: white; /* Цвет текста */
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  
   }
   .shop {
    position: absolute;
  left: 820px;
  top: 12px;
  z-index: +1;
  width: 13%;
  border: 0px solid #555;
  background: #008577; /* Цвет фона блока */
  color: white; /* Цвет текста */
  padding-left: 0px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-align: left;
  
   }
   .tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 60px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 390px;
  top: 75px;
  /* Fade in tooltip - takes 1 second to go from 0% to 100% opac: */
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
</style>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
}
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function printFunction() {
  window.print();
}
</script>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#008577">
<table id="t01" border="1" cellpadding="0" height="0px">
<fieldset><!--input type="datetime-local" id="birthdaytime" name="birthdaytime"-->
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<div align="right" style="position:absolute;top:13px;right:137px;">
<input type="submit" class="submit" alt="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div align="right" style="position:absolute;top:13px;right:75px;">
<input type="image" onclick="window.open('https://yedoy.ru/get_money_buy_print_id.php')" width="50" height="50">
</div>
<div align="right" style="position:absolute;top:13px;right:15px;">
<input type="image1" onclick="window.open('https://yedoy.ru/get_money_sell_print_id.php')" width="50" height="50">    
</div>
<div align="left" style="position:absolute;top:13px;left:15px;">
<input type="button1" onclick="window.open('https://yedoy.ru/money_list.php')" width="50" height="50">    
</div>
<div align="left" style="position:absolute;top:13px;left:65px;">
<input type="button2" onclick="window.open('https://yedoy.ru/shop_list.php')" width="50" height="50">    
</div>
<div class="tooltip"  align="right" style="position:absolute;top:13px;right:137px;"><img title="Toplam" src="https://yedoy.ru//img/echo.png" style="position:absolute;top:1px;right:60px;" width="50" height="50"><span class="tooltiptext">
<b><font color="green">&nbsp;Toplam Mədaxil&nbsp;<?
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn, "SELECT SUM(`balans_medaxil`) AS `summa` FROM kassa") or die(mysqli_error($con->myconn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$stoklist = array();
echo $row["summa"];}
?>
</b> 
Azn
<hr> 
<b><font color="green">&nbsp;Toplam Məxaric&nbsp;<?
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn, "SELECT SUM(`balans_mexaric`)AS `summa` FROM kassa") or die(mysqli_error($con->myconn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$stoklist = array();
echo $row["summa"];}
?>
</b> 
Azn
<hr> 
<b><font color="green">&nbsp;Toplam Borc&nbsp;<?
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn, "SELECT SUM(`balans_borc`) AS `summa` FROM kassa") or die(mysqli_error($con->myconn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
$stoklist = array();
echo $row["summa"];}
?>
</b> 
Azn
</span>
</div>
<div align="center">
<input style="width:10%; height:25px;" type="number" min="1" max="99999" id="balans_medaxil" name="balans_medaxil" placeholder="Mədaxil">&nbsp;
<input style="width:6%; height:25px;background:#008577;color:white;" type="text" id="data" name="data" value="<?php echo $data = date("d.m.Y") ?>" disabled>
<input style="width:10%; height:25px;" type="number" min="1" max="99999" id="balans_mexaric" name="balans_mexaric" placeholder="Məxaric">

<input style="width:10%; height:25px;" type="text" id="melumat" name="melumat" placeholder="Məlumat">
<select required class="car" name="info" id="info" autofocus>
<option hidden="" disabled="disabled" selected="" value="">Digər məsrəf va zərərlər</option>
  <option value="Xarab Çörək">Xarab Çörək</option>
  <option value="Nağd Müştəri">Nağd Müştəri</option>
  <option value="Daxili Borc Alacaqları">Daxili Borc Alacaqları</option>
  <option value="Bazar">Bazar</option>
  <option value="Məhərrəm Şirniyyat">Məhərrəm Şirniyyat</option>
  <option value="Zəngəzur Un">Zəngəzur Un</option>
  <option value="Paket">Paket</option>
  <option value="Elnur Şirniyyat">Elnur Şirniyyat</option>
  <option value="Alapala">Alapala</option>
  <option value="Komunal Xərc">Komunal Xərc</option>
  <option value="Yol Xərci">Yol Xərci</option>
  <option value="Avadanlıq">Avadanlıq</option>
  <option value="Avtomobil">Avtomobil</option>
  <option value="Yanacaq">Yanacaq</option>
  <option value="Fəhlə Pulu">Fəhlə Pulu</option>
  <option value="GPS">GPS</option>
  <option value="Rabitə">Rabitə</option>
  <option value="Dəftərxana Xərci">Dəftərxana Xərci</option>
  <option value="Yemək Xərci">Yemək Xərci</option>
  <option value="Mükafat">Mükafat</option>
  <option value="Təsərüfat">Təsərüfat</option>
  <option value="Tikinti">Tikinti</option>
  <option value="Mətbəə">Mətbəə</option>
  <option value="Vergi">Vergi</option>
  <option value="Almanya">Almanya</option>
  
</select>
</form>
<?
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn, "SELECT * FROM `kassa` ORDER BY `kassa`.`user_name` ASC LIMIT 100") or die(mysqli_error($con->myconn));
echo '<form  method="post" name="frmProduct" id="frmProduct"  enctype="multipart/form-data">';
echo '<select required name="username" id="user" onchange="myFunctions()" autofocus>';
echo '<option hidden="" disabled="disabled" selected="" value="">S/T</option>';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
unset($user_name);
$user_name = $row['user_name']; 
echo '<option value="'.$user_name.'">'.$user_name.'</option>';
}

echo '</select>&nbsp;';
echo '</form> ';
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
$result2 = mysqli_query($con->myconn, 'SELECT `uid` FROM `kassa` WHERE `user_name` = "'.$_POST['username'].'"') or die(mysql_error());
while ($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
   $user = $row['uid'];
}
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn, 'SELECT * FROM `shop_list` WHERE `user` = "'.$user.'" ORDER BY `shop_list`.`nameshop` DESC LIMIT 200') or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<select required  class="shop" name="shop_name" id="shop"  autofocus>';
echo '<option hidden="" disabled="disabled" selected="" value="">Müştəri Adi seçin</option>';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
unset($shop_name);
$shop_name = $row['nameshop']; 
echo '<option value="'.$shop_name.'">'.$shop_name.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';



}
}
?>
<script>

document.getElementById("user").onchange = submitAction;

function submitAction()
{
    document.getElementById("frmProduct").submit();
    return false;
}

</script>

</div>

</fieldset>
<hr>
<thead>
<tr>
<th><font color="#FFDD00">S/T:</font></th>
<th><font color="#FFFAFA">Mədaxil</font></th>
<th><font color="#FFFAFA">Məxaric</font></th>
<th><font color="#FFFAFA">Borc</font></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?
$result = mysqli_query($con->myconn, "SELECT * FROM `kassa` ORDER BY `kassa`.`data` ASC") or die(mysqli_error($con->myconn));
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
<tr>
<td><p>&nbsp;<b><font color="#0068BE"><? echo $row['user_name']; ?></font></b></p></td>
<td><p><center><b><font color="#14BE0B"><? echo $row['balans_medaxil']; ?></font></b></center></p></td>
<td><p><center><b><font color="#BE110B"><? echo $row['balans_mexaric']; ?></font></b></center></p></td>
<td><p><center><b><font color="#595044"><? echo $row['balans_borc']; ?></font></b></center></p></td>
</tr>
<? } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы делаете это через `<form  method="post".....`. Если жизненно необходимо использовать форму, то - `preventDefault` + `Ajax`. Либо просто (без формы) `Ajax`.

Comment: вы можете привести пример если не трудно у меня апять не получается